# Using chrome.downloads.download, is it possible to make the file not popup the download bar?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

When I executed [chrome.downloads.download](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/downloads#method-download), it downloads the file and popups up the download bar at the bottom and shows it, can I suppress it?

Example:

```
/* some code to suppress download bar */

chrome.downloads.download(
  { "url": request.ImageToDownload },
  function (downloadId){
    // ...
  }
);
```

Comment: I hope to God not... (as an end-user)

Comment: no, downloads go to downloads, that's what the tool is for.

Comment: Downloads can go to downloads, we just don't want the pixel space taken up at the bottom because of it, in some situations.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. You can [fully suppress the download bar](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/downloads#method-setShelfEnabled):

> ```
> chrome.downloads.setShelfEnabled(boolean enabled)
> ```
>
> Enable or disable the gray shelf at the bottom of every window associated with the current browser profile. The shelf will be disabled as long as at least one extension has disabled it. Enabling the shelf while at least one other extension has disabled it will return an error through `runtime.lastError`. Requires the `"downloads.shelf"` permission in addition to the `"downloads"` permission.

Make sure to restore it after you're done. The idea of this function is to allow you to build a custom UI that replaces the shelf.