# How do I hide the download bar in a chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

Is there a way to hide the downloads bar appearing at the bottom programatically after a download is complete in a chrome extension?

I have tried this but did not work:
chrome.downloads.setShelfEnabled(false);

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using chrome.downloads.download, is it possible to make the file not popup the download bar?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28752268/using-chrome-downloads-download-is-it-possible-to-make-the-file-not-popup-the-d)

Answer (score -1):

There is no such feature provided by Chrome. You can hide the downloads automatically by using the following extension:
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/always-clear-downloads/cpbmgiffkljiglnpdbljhlenaikojapc/related

In case you want to go through the Downloads list, there is always the option of using Ctrl + J

Comment: This person is obviously doing their own chrome extension. Unless you got the source code to the extension you mention in link that can help solve this problem, this answer just informs readers to keep searching...